# QTableView added in designer: not showing data

Tags: qt, qtableview

I have found example how to use `QTableView`:
http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/sql-querymodel.html
It works fine. Data is shown in `QTableView`.

But `QTableView` in this example is created dynamically in `main.cpp` file. 
In my application I have main form and I added `QTableView` in designer. I try to populate this `QTableView` in constructor but without result:

```
MainApplication::MainApplication(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainApplication)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);


    QMap<QString, double> currencyMap;
        currencyMap.insert("AUD", 1.3259);
        currencyMap.insert("CHF", 1.2970);
        currencyMap.insert("CZK", 24.510);


        CurrencyModel currencyModel;
        currencyModel.setCurrencyMap(currencyMap);

      ui->tableView_currencies->setModel(&currencyModel);
      ui->tableView_currencies->setAlternatingRowColors(true);

      ui->tableView_currencies->setWindowTitle(QObject::tr("Currencies"));
      ui->tableView_currencies->show();

}
```

`QTableView` is showing on main form empty, only columns and rows headers are visible. And data is not shown.

Does anybody know of a site with examples where components like `QTableView`, `QListView` are added in designer? In trolltech (nokia) tutorials all components are created dynamically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The model is no longer valid after the constructor is executed!
You create a local object `currencyModel` that will be destroyed when it goes out of scope (at the end of the c'tor), but pass a pointer to it as the model for the table view!
The table view doesn't deep-copy the given model, and in fact doesn't even take ownership of the passed pointer:

> The view does not take ownership of the model unless it is the model's parent object because the view may be shared between many different views.
>   ([QTableView doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setModel))

You should simply allocate the model no the heap (using `new`) and set the view as it's parent object. in that way, the table view will also handle its deletion:

```
CurrencyModel *currencyModel = new CurrencyModel(ui->tableView_currencies);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used QTableWidget rather than QTableView with great success in designer.

If you really want to understand why the *View's aren't working while *Widgets are, you should use designer/moc to produce the code and compare them to each other, then compare to the working *View examples. Personally, I was satisfied when the *Widget types worked so I stopped looking; *Widget inherits from *View.

Comment: Ok, but what with model/view implement.

Answer (score -1):

I met and you the same question king_nak is right your currencyModel is Temporary variables;

```
QxCurrencyModel* currencyModel = new QxCurrencyModel;
```